# How to find gradient of $f(v,w)=Av·w$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, partial-derivative, vector-analysis

I have a question:

> Let $A ∈ R^{m×n}$, and consider critical points of $f(v,w)=Av·w$, $v∈R^n, w∈R^m$

I need to find the gradient of $f(v,w)$ to solve it. I write $f(v,w)$ by double sum form but then I get stuck.
$f(v,w)=\sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}v_jw_i$. To get $\nabla f$, how can I derive the partial derivative of $v$ if $f$ is written by components of $v$?

Comment: What variables are the $a_{ij}$ functions of?  It looks like just a very long product rule.

Comment: You don't derive the partial derivative of $v$ by itself, but the partial derivatives by its components, and that's straightforward.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor $a_{ij}$ stands for entries of $A$

Comment: @uniquesolution Can I combine all partial derivatives by its components to get the partial derivative of $v$? I'm a little confused

Comment: @Kylinny, I get that, I was asking what variables you are differentiating with respect to.  Are they functions of $t$? $x,y,z$? Something else?  Mostly I was wondering if you are doing a single derivative or an actual gradient.  Again, where are you stuck?

Comment: Quite similar to your previous question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4073022). Why don't you mention it ?

Comment: @RobertTheTutor I was differentiating $f$ with respect to $v$. Partial derivative. I thought I may just figure it out. Would it just be $A^T w$ ?

Comment: That is correct, I just checked with a $2x2$ example.